# How can I access git version information from inside my Clojure app on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, clojure

I have working code on my personal machine that executes `git describe` via clojure.java.shell and shows that version info on the settings page.  But when this runs on Heroku, even adjusting the path to the same one I get from `which git` on a `heroku run bash` prompt, I get this error:

{:exit 128, :out , :err fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /app)}

And checking from the heroku bash prompt again, I see no .git directory.

How could I access the current git tag and SHA from inside my Clojure app?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't give you access to this directory, the slug compiler strips it before build time.

> Step 2: Remove unused files, including .git directories, .gitmodules files, anything in log and tmp, and anything specified in a top-level .slugignore file.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

There are some circuitous workarounds suggested in [Heroku - Display hash of current commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583282/heroku-display-hash-of-current-commit).

See also https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli/issues/14 for discussion about why providing the .gif folder could be a bad idea. Short answer: size, and that the .git directory is not always provided by the user in different deploy modes.